Total space of the frame bundle always an almost complex manifold in $dim >2$?
I seem to remember reading that the total space of the frame bundle of a smooth Riemannian manifold always admits an almost complex structure in dimensions greater than 2.
However now I can't seem to find any reference to this, did my memory just make it up? I know it's trivially true for the tangent bundle.
I know it IS always parallelizable so we know the second steifel-whitney class vanishes.  And of course that its even dimensional.

Every parallelisable even-dimensional manifold admits almost complex structures. Can you see why?

@MichaelAlbanese  lol yes, I didn't even think about global framings, its late on a Friday.  Quick counter question: Under what conditions is the almost complex structure compatible with the splitting (Whitney sum) of the tangent space of the frame bundle induced by a connection?  I'd expect that the base space would also have to be almost complex as well (though I'm hoping there's a workaround)?

The orthogonal frame bundle is even-dimensional iff $n\equiv 0,1\bmod 4$ where $n$ is the dimension of the base. The tangent bundle of the frame bundle splits. The vertical bundle is trivial and the horizontal bundle is isomorphic to the pullback of the tangent bundle of the base. For this to be a splitting of complex vector bundles, the bundles need to have even rank, so $n\equiv 0\bmod 4$. The vertical bundle, being trivial, admits an almost complex structure. If the base admits an almost complex structure, then the horizontal bundle does too, but its not clear whether this is necessary.

@MichaelAlbanese  Thank you, I get that  even dimensional spin manifolds admit almost complex structures, which made me think we can do a trick.. By projecting a linear connection on the frame bundle to the base we obtain a second order connection (Kolar I think)  on the base.  This extra connection term has a structure group and COULD allow us to define a generalized spin structure on the base and some accompanying almost complex structure.  (Like $Spin_\mathbb{C}$ structures but with larger group).  Does that sound feasable? and maybe the same for higher order frame bundles?

@MichaelAlbanese  I suppose though that only splits the tangent space of the frame bundle of the frame bundle $TFFM=TM \oplus \mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}'$ where $g$ is the Lie algebra of the frame bundles structure group and $g'$ is the Lie algebra of $FFM$'s structure group over $FM$.  This consideration is  what lead to my question in the first place.

@MichaelAlbanese Motivation:  Beginning with Euclidean metric an orientable spacetime has a 10 dimensional principal $SO(4)$ frame bundle $F_{oo}M$.  If we consider frames on this bundle they transform under $GL(10,\mathbb{C})$   The AC structure though reduces this to $U(5)$.  A splitting induced by a connection makes this $U(2) \times U(3)$  and orientation induced by that on $M$ yields $S(U(2) \times U(3))$ which is isomorphic to $(SU(2)\times U(1) \times SU(3))/\mathbb{Z}_6$ which is precisely the full gauge group of the standard model of particle physics. true for any orientable spacetime

@MichaelAlbanese  I was trying to look at higher order approximations to the group of local charts  rather than the standard 1-jet approach in general relativity (i.e. the invertible bundle of 1-jets of local charts aka the frame bundle).  Thought it was interesting that a second order approach yields the above.  The change back to lorentzian signature will break some of the above group $(SU(2)\times U(1) \rightarrow U(1)$? I don't know  yet, but it's fascinating at the very least.

@MichaelAlbanese  ERRATA: the frames on $F_oo M$ transform under $Gl(10,\mathbb{R})$ the AC structure reduces this to $GL(5,\mathbb{C})$ and a choice of hermitian metric reduces further to $U(5)$ I was typing in a hurry, because I decided I finally wanted to share this interesting thing.

@MichaelAlbanese  However I can't tell if $M$ has to admit an almost complex structure for this to occur... hence my question. Really I just wanted to consider general relativity with covariance brought to higher order in the local charts $M \supset U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ rather than the 1-jets  of local diffeomorphisms everyone uses. Note the Ricci curvature scalar of higher order connections has Yang-mills like terms involving curvatures of the higher order connection terms (and hence their structure groups) This can be looked at similarly to Kaluza-klein esque programs.

I'm not going to address all of your comments (maybe it would be better to put them in a new question), but let me just point out that even-dimensional spin manifolds do not necessarily admit almost complex structures, e.g. $S^4$.

@MichaelAlbanese I'm confused $S^4$ isn't parallelizable which is required for a spin structure

@MichaelAlbanese. The only spheres that are as I'm sure you know are in dim 1,3,7

Parallelizability is not required for a spin structure. Recall, a smooth manifold $M$ is spin if and only if $w_1(M) = 0$ and $w_2(M) = 0$. Every parallelizable manifold is spin, but not every spin manifold is parallelizable, e.g. $S^4$.
